# Hyperunique Aggregations in Calcite-Druid Adapter

Tags: druid, apache-calcite

In my Druid data source, I have a hyperUnique aggregation (ingestion time) on one of the fields.

I am trying to do the equivalent of `COUNT(DISTINCT(<hyperunique_field>))` on this aggregated field.

Is it supported in the Calcite Druid Adapter? If so, what is the correct way to go about it?

In plywood, I can do `COUNT_DISTINCT`. Running this returns 0 counts.

**SQL:**

> select floor("__time" to HOUR) time_bucket,”field_1", count(distinct(“ingestion_time_aggregated_field"))  as uniq from “datasource" where "__time" between '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-02 00:00:00' and “field_1" in (‘value_1') and “field_2”='value_2' and “field_3”='value_3' and “field_4”='value_4' group by floor("__time" to HOUR),”field_1" order by floor("__time" to HOUR);

**ingestion_time_aggregated_field**:

```
{"name": "ingestion_time_aggregated_field", "type": "hyperUnique","fieldName": “field” }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex aggregators are not supported by the calcite-druid adapted.  The reason is that HLL is an approximate and not exact so it does not actually answer to the query of unique count.